# javascript: understanding the flow of a fibonacci recursive statement

Tags: javascript, recursion

I eventually want to get the hang of dynamic programming but before that, I am having a hard time understanding the flow of this. I understand recursion but I'm having trouble understanding the flow of this:

```js
function fib(n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
console.log(fib(3));
```

if I have a small integer of `3`, it does not pass those 2 conditionals so it hits `return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);` So to my understanding, that will go through the first part of that first: `fib(n-1)` (3-1 = 2)... `2` does not satisfy either of those conditionals so it runs `fib(n-1)` (2-1 = 1).  `1` DOES satisfy one of the conditionals so it `returns 1` and breaks that part of it.

Now to to the next part: `fib(n-2)` .  (3-2 = 1).  `1` does satisfy one of the conditionals so it `returns 1` . 
So in the end, isn't that returning `1 + 1` ?

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in my understanding.

Comment: Yes, it is returning 1 + 1 = 2. 2 *is* the third element in the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @CertainPerformance if it only returns 1 or 0, how is it ever greater than 2 then?

Comment: Because higher calls of `fib` like `fib(4)` will result in multiple (eventual) reductions to sums of `fib(1)`.

Comment: @user10108817 consider the case of `fib(4)`. What does the tree of recursive calls look like then? You'll see that you can indeed get a result greater than 2.

Comment: To be exact, the first part `fib(2)` returns `fib(2 -1) + fib(2 - 2) = 1 + 0`. I think it's easier to write it as math function expansion: `fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(0) = (fib(1) + fib(0)) + fib(0) = 2`

Comment: @YohanesGultom but when is it ever greater than `fib(2 -1) + fib(3 - 2) = 1 + 1` since `fib` won't stop running until `n` is `1` or `0`

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that `fib(3)` should return `2`, because `2` is the 3rd number in the Fibonacci sequence (starting at 0)

It helps to write out it out as tree:

```
       fib(3)
      /     \
    fib(2)   fib(1)
   /     \     \
 fib(1) fib(0)  1
 /        \  
1          0
```

above you can see how each recursive call goes all the way to 0 or 1 before returning a result back up the previous layer.

Comment: what I don't quite understand though is won't , regardless of what integer used, it keep running `return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)` until the conditional of `if (n == 0) return 0;`  or `if (n == 1) return 1;` are met?  Which means, how is the return ever greater than 2?

Comment: because statement "  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);" would add up the returned value from each iteration, and will further return to its previous iteration after the statement is executed.

Comment: @user10108817 If what you are saying is true, the result would never be greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite ways to do this is to start with the base cases and go backwards:

```
fib(0); // => 0
fib(1); // => 1
```

Then we get to the default case:

```
fib(2); // == fib(1) + fib(0) == 1 + 0 ==> 1
fib(3); // == fib(2) + fib(1) == 1 + 1 ==> 2
fib(4); // == fib(3) + fib(2) == 2 + 1 ==> 3
```

This is much easier than trying to figure out fib(4) first since you need to nest. Looking at the function it's easy to see what to try.

Also know that calls to the same function doesn't get any special treatment. It runs until it returns with a value and it's arguments and local variables are local to the call so every `fib` call has its own `n` and it waits for the two calls to return to sum the results.